# how to tackle a new project

Tags: coding-style

I have a question about best practice on how to tackle a new project, any project. When starting a new project how do you go about tackling the project, do you split it into sections, start writing code, draw up flow diagrams.

I'm asking this question because I'm looking for advice on how I can start new projects so I can get going on them quicker. I can have it planned, designed and starting coding with everything worked out.

Any advice?

Thanks

Stephen

Comment: There is an entire branch of computer science studying this, and it's called Software Engineering... use google to find out more...

Comment: When you start coding you will always find flaws in the plans and designs. Its an illusion to think that it is possible to have everything covered with the first design. Incremental development is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

It all really depends. Is the project for controlling a space shuttle with 200+ people working on it, or is it a hobby project with 1 person.

I'm guessing this is a small project. In that case, do whatever works for you. Write a list of things you think are required. If there are parts you know you need to learn more about or research, get reading the web, try some stuff out with prototype code to see whether it works or not. Don't turn prototype code into real code though, start again with production code and make sure you get all the appropriate error handling etc in.

When you think you've got a good feel for what's needed, get coding. If you hit a point where you think it's not working, go back to the design and rethink it and sketch some more diagrams, and then go back to the code again.

It is extremely doubtful that you can work everything out in your plan and that's how things will actually work out. So, there's little point in trying to plan too far ahead because you'll be wasting time. Just plan out far enough ahead to keep yourself focused on working on the right things and so that you've given yourself a reasonable chance that the code you're working on will fit the big picture and solve the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Start by writing a [simple functional spec](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000035.html), a few paragraphs from the user's perspective: what they see, how they perform actions, what they expect to happen if they click widget X. This will glue the logic together in your head, and on paper.

From there you can work on the technical spec, which details the gritty things like database structure, special controls and components you need, SDK's if any, and all other developer-type details that you need to implement.